# Cannot get data from backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am very new to backbone and I am having a bit of trouble.

So I am trying to get some data from a Model within a Collection and I cannot work out how, I am unsure if I have setup my collection incorrectly or something, but that's where I am hoping you guys can help.

Here is my code:

```
var currentPage = 1;

var Page = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        pageName: '',
        pageID: 0,
        ajaxUrl: '',
        pageUrl: '',
        hashUrl: '',
        previousPage: '',
        nextPage: ''
    }
});

var home = new Page({
    pageName: 'Home',
    pageID: 1,
    ajaxUrl: 'ajax-content/index.html',
    pageUrl: 'index.html',
    hashUrl: '#index',
    previousPage: 'Contact',
    nextPage: 'Our Approach'
});

var WebsitePages = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Page
})

var myWebsite = new WebsitePages([home]);

var ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "body",
    events: {
        'click .previous-page': 'loadPreviousPage',
        'click .next-page': 'loadNextPage'
    },
    loadPreviousPage: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pageModel = myWebsite.where({pageID: currentPage});
    },
    loadNextPage: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pageModel = myWebsite.where({pageID: currentPage});
    }
});
```

So far this has give me no luck.

I have also done a bit of debugging in the console to see if I can access it any other way. My breakpoint was placed on the `e.preventDefault()` of the `loadPreviousPage` function. Here is what I tried to do and the results I got:

```
myWebsite
s {length: 6, models: Array[6], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}

myWebsite.get('home')
undefined

myWebsite.get(0)
undefined

myWebsite.get('0')
undefined

myWebsite.where({pageID: 1})
[s]

var pageModel = myWebsite.where({pageID: 1})
undefined

pageModel
[s]

pageModel.get(pageName)
ReferenceError: pageName is not defined

pageModel.get('pageName')
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I am super confused now so if anyone could help me out that would be awesome.

Cheers.

Comment: Your collection it's well defined but [where](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) returns an array of models that match the attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code block, `currentPage` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

In your console output, `where` returns an array and you're trying to use it as a model. Try with

```
var pageModel = myWebsite.where({pageID: 1})[0];

console.log(pageModel.get('pageName'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added it in the code now, the `currentPage` variable is set in the HTML of each page which is why I missed it in the code. adding `[0]` worked, thanks so much. I understand that adding that will get me the first part of the array but I don't understand why that is required.

Comment: It's required because `where` returns an array. To access a model in the array, simply access it with `myArray[0]`: it's equivalent to `var myArray = myWebsite.where({pageID: 1})` followed by `var pageModel = myArray[0]`